# can't replace teapot with banana

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, augmented-reality, vuforia

I downloaded banana.h file from http://heikobehrens.net/2009/08/27/obj2opengl/. I included .h file in EAGLView.mm. I replaced in EAGLView.mm file. I followed instruction for replace teapot with another 3D modal. But i didn't get any output for replacing. I don't know where i did mistake

```
namespace {    
    // Teapot texture filenames    
    const char* textureFilenames[] = {    
    "banana.jpg",    
    /*

    "TextureTeapotBrass.png",
    "TextureTeapotBlue.png",
    "TextureTeapotRed.png"
    */
    }

    // Model scale factor
    const float kObjectScale = 3.0f;
}

- (void) setup3dObjects    
{    
    // build the array of objects we want drawn and their texture    
    // in this example we have 3 targets and require 3 models
    // but using the same underlying 3D model of a teapot, differentiated
    // by using a different texture for each

    for (int i=0; i < [textures count]; i++)
    {
        Object3D *obj3D = [[Object3D alloc] init];
    //  obj3D.numVertices = NUM_TEAPOT_OBJECT_VERTEX;

        obj3D.numVertices =bananaNumVerts;
        obj3D.vertices = bananaVerts;
        obj3D.normals = bananaNormals;
        obj3D.texCoords = bananaTexCoords;
        obj3D.numIndices = 0;
        obj3D.indices = nil;
        obj3D.texture = [textures objectAtIndex:i];

        [objects3D addObject:obj3D];
        [obj3D release];
    }
}
```

In renderFrame replaced:

```
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, bananaVerts);    
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, bananaNormals);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, bananaTexCoords);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, bananaNumVerts);
```

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: There is a discussion about this here that might help you: https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/ios/different-3d-model-not-shown (note that it reads from the bottom to top)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is right. Try increasing scale size because you model might be very small. Change

```
const float kObjectScale = 50.0f; // Scale up
```

And also use .png format for texture.